# managing ID's in android layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know whether i am asking the right question or a wrong one.
it may sound foolish but still i feel to clear my basic doubts.
the question is:
i have three different layout files for a single activity.
depending upon the purpose for which the activity is started, it will take one of these layout files as its content.
these layouts have various fields in common.
i have a question that in these different layout files can i have the same "id's" for the common fields.

for ex:  i have a save button for all the three layouts.
in all those three layout files..... can i have (For the button)

```
android:id="@+id/save_button"
```

the same ID attribute in all the three files.

i require this because i have too many elements(components) in my layout files.
if they can be identified with common names (as they serve the same purpose in their respective layouts) there would be very less names/ids to remember, which will make my program easy to be readable and less things for me to remember.
else i will have to write the same code for components with same functionality.

thankyou in advance.
your answers will help me clear my doubts. please correct me if i am moving with wrong concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this allowed, but I would encourage it. Using the same id across files allows you to create new layout files without having to change any of the code referencing the button. As long as the id is descriptive of what it relates to, then it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: thankyou very much , it will save me a lot of time and work :)